# Universal link doesnt work in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I have configured Universal link for my Xamarin.iOS. But when I click on the app I always redirect to the web site. Then I created a new native iOS application and it works fine. then I created an empty Xamarin.iOS project and it doesn't work. Do I need to do something additional for Xamarin.iOS than iOS native?

Comment: Have you enabled and added the Associated Domains in your project's Entitlements.plist? XCode will automatically configure this setting in the Capability tab. But you have to set it manually in VS and register the corresponding App ID with that capability on Apple portal.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
 <array>
  <string>applinks:still-shelf-93.herokuapp.com</string>
 </array> this is my Entitlements.plist. I am using same appid for native and xamarin.ios(for testing) so this would have been configured I think

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT and yes I can see Associated domains have been ticked in my App ID in developer portal

Comment: And the project which you created using Xamarin has the same bundle ID as the portal?

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT yes both have the same bundle id

Comment: Compare the info.plist files for the two, and the entitlements file if there is one. Do you see any differences?

Comment: @Saamer I compared Entitlement.plist and both are same